# Grails: ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in WAR deployment

Tags: mysql, tomcat, grails, gradle

This is an issue that just started happening recently and its only with specific projects and WAR deployment.  I am not able to deploy a WAR file because I get the following exception

```
ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:712)
 [.....]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
```

Nothing in my project has changed since my last successful deploy (I verify with git) and I can run the project fine using Spring Boot.

The mysql-connector is in my gradle build

`runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.46'`  (I have also tried changing to `compile`)

I have the driver declared properly in my `application.yml`

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: ****
    password: ****

environments:
    production:
        dataSource:
          password: *****
          dbCreate: none
          url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp
```

I am using Intellij IDE and can confirm that the mysql-connector is listed in my classpath and when I explode my WAR file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar` is listed in my `WEB-INF/lib`

I have done multiple cleans and rebuilds of the project.  I am really at a loss for what is happening and as mentioned its only specific projects.  I have other grails projects with identical config setups and deploy just fine but a handful of others give me this error.  Any ideas?

Tomcat: 7.0.70

Java: 1.8.0_91

MySQL: 5.6 and 5.7 (fails on both)

Grails: 3.3.1

**Update:**
So if I put my mysql jar in my Tomcat lib folder instead of my project lib folder then it works.  So that proves that the JAR file is valid.  When I put the JAR file back into the WEB-INF/lib folder of my app then it doesn't work.  So it seems for some reason the JAR file is being ignored or not loaded when its packaged with my app.  Again though, its just some apps.  I have other apps that works just fine with the lib packaged with the app.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure. It's not issue of jar file.

You can check [here in repo](https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.46/) and [here](https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/mysql/mysql-connector-java/) for all versions of MySQL connectors

Please verify your dependency `runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.46"`

Verify your system MySQL server user and password and `dataSource` username , password.

Verify  your MySQL running fine with valid credentials.

Because `ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.` this error will come when MySQL is not running on system or invalid username password.

One more possibility of error:
If you have updated your MySQL version. It will try to connect securely.
So by you need to pass some parameters to URL `mysql://localhost:3306/yourDb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true`

Last option if you are not resolved problem:
Update your dependency and configuration with latest version.

Dependency for your reference:
`runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6"`

and `Application.yml`

```
dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                pooled: true
                url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourDb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
                driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
                username: yourUsername
                password: yourPassword
                properties:
...
```

`driverClassName` have been changed in latest version.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried your ideas but unfortunately didn't work.  I did make some progress though, if you don't mind please look at my post update.  thanks!

Comment: You are deploying war to tomcat?

Comment: Yes I'm using tomcat.  I have tried multiple versions of tomcat as well

Comment: why you are not running war directly ? with integrated tomcat

Comment: If you're referring to those standalone self deploying webapps then that wouldn't work for our environment